# How to get a blinking link on Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

The JavaScript below causes some text to blink on a web page. When I use it with an anchor tag on Blogger it only acts like a link and does not blink. If it is not an anchor tag it will blink. Is there any way to get around this on Blogger?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function blinker()
{
    if(document.getElementById("blink"))
    {
        var d = document.getElementById("blink") ;
        d.style.color= (d.style.color=='red'?'white':'red');
        setTimeout('blinker()', 500);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="blinker();">
    <div id="blink">GOOGLE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<a href="www.google.com">link text</a>` http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: I know that. But when i add a hperlink to that above code, blinking stops and hyperlink  works

Comment: `<a href="//google.com" id="blink">link text</a>`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function blinker() {
  if (document.getElementById("blink")) {
    var d = document.getElementById("blink");
    d.style.color = (d.style.color == 'red' ? 'white' : 'red');
    setTimeout('blinker()', 500);
  }
}

blinker();
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" id="blink">GOOGLE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="blink"><a href="www.google.com">GOOGLE</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      <script type="text/javascript"> function blinker() {
          if(document.getElementById("blink"))
          {
              var d = document.getElementById("blink") ;
              d.style.color= (d.style.color=='red'?'white':'red');
              setTimeout('blinker()', 500);
          } } </script>

      <body onload="blinker();">
 <div id="blink"> <a href="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a></div> </body>
```

Basically, you need to add an href element.

Comment: I'm getting error "Your HTML cannot be accepted: Tag is not closed: DIV Dismiss" I already tried all this but I'm getting error. That's why asked

Comment: Tried only the code you gave me. Blinking stops when there's hyperlink. If kink is removed, blinking works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this. It uses JavaScript to treat the div a link. Looks like StackOverflow blocks that though, which is understandable. It should still work for you on other pages. Note however that the user won't see what's on the other side if they hover their mouse over it, and the cursor won't change to indicate it is clickable.

```js
function blinker() {
  if (document.getElementById("blink")) {
    var d = document.getElementById("blink");
    d.style.color = (d.style.color == 'red' ? 'white' : 'red');
    setTimeout('blinker()', 500);
  }
}

function goto(page) {
    document.location = page;
}

blinker();
```

```html
<div onclick="goto('https://www.google.com/')" id="blink">GOOGLE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found answer myself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function blinker()
{
    if(document.getElementById("blink"))
    {
        var d = document.getElementById("blink") ;
        d.style.color= (d.style.color=='red'?'white':'red');
        setTimeout('blinker()', 500);
    }
}
</script>

<body onload="blinker();">
<a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="blink">GOOGLE</div></a>
</body>
```

Thanks everybody for helping